# Calculate node metrics based on attribute value

Tags: r, igraph

I often want to calculate a metric for all vertices in a graph, but only based on their connections to vertices with a certain attribute, take for example the graph

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(2)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(8, 0.5)

V(g)$name <- paste0("ID", 1:8)
V(g)$rand_attr <- rep(c("A", "B"), 4)

plot(g,
     vertex.label = paste(V(g)$name, V(g)$rand_attr),
     vertex.shape = "none")
```

[image: example graph]

Now suppose I want to count the number of type "B" connections for every vertex. The only way I can think to do this is by creating a series of subgraphs which include the focal vertex and all "B" vertices, like so

```
for (i in V(g)$name) {
  subg <- induced_subgraph(g, 
                     vids = c(which(V(g)$name == i), which(V(g)$rand_attr == "B")))
  d <- degree(subg, v = which(V(subg)$name == i))
  print(d)
}
ID1 
  3 
ID2 
  2
ID3 
  3  
...
```

This gives me the output I want, but feels a bit clunky and inefficient. Is there a built-in function or some better way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Other than the display of the answer, your solution seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try getting the names of "B" vertices. Then using the function adjacent_vertices can return the names of adjacent vertices for each vertice. Then it's a matter of counting how many of each connected vertice is in our list.

```
# your code, just to store the numbers
n <- vector("numeric",length(V(g)))
names(n) <- V(g)$name

for(i in V(g)$name){
  subg <- induced_subgraph(g, 
                vids = c(which(V(g)$name == i), which(V(g)$rand_attr == "B")))
  d <- degree(subg, v = which(V(subg)$name == i))
  n[i] <- d
}

n
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 ID8 
  3   2   3   3   1   2   1   3 

#names of B vertices
Bvert = vertex.attributes(g)$name[vertex.attributes(g)$rand_attr=="B"]
#number of B vertices connected per vertice 
N = sapply(adjacent_vertices(g,1:8),function(i)sum(names(i) %in% Bvert))

N
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 ID5 ID6 ID7 ID8 
  3   2   3   3   1   2   1   3

table(N==n)
```